# Woocommerce - Modificar totales en checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy desarrollando un sitio en Wordpress que utiliza Woocommerce. Necesito añadir una tarifa extra a ciertos clientes, por lo que al valor total del carrito en el checkout debo agregarles un incremento según ciertas condiciones.

Descubrí que puedo utilizar un Hook de Woocommerce para añadir una tarifa extra al checkout, pero esta se agrega siempre y yo busco que solo se ejecute si el cliente cumple con determinada condición. Les dejo el código para que tengan una idea:

```
function nuevo_precio() {
// Calcula el impuesto a añadir
$carrito = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;

$adicional = $carrito * 0.21;

$precio_formateado = wc_price($adicional);

$nombre_impuesto = 'Adicionales';

// Añade el impuesto al carrito
WC()->cart->add_fee($nombre_impuesto, $adicional, false, '');

}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'nuevo_precio');
```

Ese código es sólo de prueba y funciona. Cuando voy al Checkout de mi sitio actualiza los valores y añade el impuesto.

Entonces como necesito que se ejecute solo cuando se cumpla cierta condición hago lo siguiente:

functions.php

```
function nuevo_precio() {
if (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX) {
    // Si la función se activa a través de AJAX, ejecuta el código aquí
    // Calcula el impuesto a añadir
    $carrito = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
    $adicional = $carrito * 0.21;
    $precio_formateado = wc_price($adicional);
    $nombre_impuesto = 'Adicionales';
    // Añade el impuesto al carrito
    WC()->cart->add_fee($nombre_impuesto, $adicional, false, '');
    echo $precio_formateado;
 }
}

// Llama al JS
function enqueue_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-cart', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-cart.js', 
array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_scripts');


// Ejecuta la función que calcula el nuevo precio
add_action('wp_ajax_activar_nuevo_precio', 'activar_nuevo_precio');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_activar_nuevo_precio', 'activar_nuevo_precio'); 

function activar_nuevo_precio() {
    nuevo_precio();
}
```

Y por otro lado tengo un JS que ejecuta todo lo anterior en un determinado momento:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#billing_wooccm11').on('input', function() {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    if (inputVal.length === 11) {
        // Cuando el campo tenga 11 caracteres, ejecutar AJAX para activar la función en PHP
        $.ajax({
            url: woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'activar_nuevo_precio'
            },
            success: function(response) {
                // Recargar el carrito después de agregar la tarifa extra
                $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                alert(response)
            }
        });
      }
  });
});
```

La cuestión es que todo se esta ejecutando correctamente, porque mediante el "alert()" que esta en el JS compruebo que la salida de mi función es la que espero, pero el problema es que mi carrito no se está actualizando.
Ya le di mil vueltas y no consigo dar con la manera de resolver esto, si alguno me puede dar una mano le estaré agradecido!